# Exception View size is too small after padding is applied. (using newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int))

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an android app. In this app I am showing a MapView in a fragment. My app gets crashed when i include following code in Activity.

```
 LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
 builder.include(pickupLatLng);
 builder.include(destinationLatLng);
 LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

 int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
 int padding = (int) (width*0.2);

 CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
 mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pickupLatLng).title("pickup location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_pickup)));
 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(destinationLatLng).title("destination"));
```

It shows error at this line:

```
mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

Comment: Can you share the full and exact error message?

Comment: what was the issue?

Answer (score 3):

The problem happens when the padding is greater than the height. Take into account the screen height:

```
int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
int padding = (int) (Math.min(width, height)*0.2);
```